# ¿Porque me agrega la clase next left en mi carousel de boostrap cuando le indico que me agregue mi clase active en mi carousel de boostrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando mi pregunta tenga un timer y el usuario le de en siguiente, esa pregunta desaparezca y ya no la pueda contestar.

Código:

```
var timer = $(".active").attr('data-timer');
if (timer == undefined) {
    var $carousel = $('#carousel');
    var NextElement = $carousel.next('.item').first();
    NextElement.addClass('active');
    $('.timer').remove();
} else {
    var $carousel = $('#carousel');
    var ActiveElement = $carousel.find('.item.active');
    ActiveElement.remove();
    var NextElement = $carousel.next('.item');
    NextElement.addClass('active');
    $('.timer').remove();
}
```

Realiza todo, salvo que cuando entra al else en vez de añadirme el active en mi carousel me añade la clase next left.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En vez de que esa clase se agregue debería de ir la de active, por ende cuando vuelve a entrar al if ya no funciona el slide.

Inclusive ya agregue lo siguiente:

```
var NextElement = $carousel.next('.item');
```

Pero sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Creo que cuando utilizas la función attr() te falta agregar un parametro

```
$(selector).attr(attribute,value)
```

Puedes consultar esta documentación y verificar si es el problema 
[Javascript attr()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp)